# Add langmap and keymap to vim in mac

Tags: macos, vim

The following outputs when I run:

```
vim --version

VIM -Vi IMproved 8.0 ...
Included patches: 1-503, 505-642
Compiled by root@apple.com
Normal version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):

...
- langmap
- keymap 
...
```

As a result I can't use `set langmap=...`.  How do I add this feature to the mac vim, so I can duplicate my linux vim environment?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order to provide the `ex` and `vi` commands that are expected on a UNIX-lookallike system, MacOS does exactly the same thing as every other UNIX-lookalike system: it ships with a limited `vi` clone.

To get a proper Vim on MacOS you do exactly the same thing as you'd do on every UNIX-lookalike: you install it.

[MacVim](http://macvim-dev.github.io/macvim/) has those features built-in.

Comment: Downvoted because this is not a terminal app, but a separate standalone app

Comment: @JeffDavenport MacVim provides both a GUI version and a TUI version. Downvote when you know, not when you don't.

Comment: Can you add the information about the terminal version so that I can change my vote?